# Why Traefik discovers container IP address on backend network?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

Using [Traefik basic example](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/basic-example/) with 2 services: `traefik` itself and `traefik/whoami`, I assigned both services to a network called `web` and the latter to `backend` network as well.

However, Traefik discovers `backend` IP address for `traefik/whoami` service and is unable to make contact via `web` network and results in "Gateway Timeout"

In attempt to force Traefik to use web network, i added `--providers.docker.network=web` and `traefik.docker.network=web` as well, but still it discovers `backend` IP address.

How can I make Traefik to discover the service IP address on the correct network?

Here's the `docker-compose.yml` file I'm trying to get to work.

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.3"
    command:
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --api.debug=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --providers.docker.network=web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - web

  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.docker.network=web
    networks:
      - web
      - backend

networks:
  web:
  backend:
```

**PS!** When you remove the `backend` network from the service, it works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one little glitch with the network names. As you are running in a compose file and don't reference an external network, the network names are created in the scope of the current `compose project`. When starting up, you might see some message saying

```
Creating network "traefik2-test_web" with the default driver
Creating network "traefik2-test_backend" with the default driver
```

(assuming the folder you are running in is called traefik2-test) This means the docker networks created are prefixed with the project name, which e.g. allows to spin up the compose file twice for isolated instances.

You might also see some error in the logs indicating that the configured network named `web` was not found - hence it falls back to randomly choosing one.

```
traefik_1  | time="2020-10-29T14:24:25Z" level=warning msg="Could not find network named 'web' for container '/traefik2-test_whoami_1'! Maybe you're missing the project's prefix in the label? Defaulting to first available network." providerName=docker container=whoami-traefik2-test-4661d09157cf941b7efd7c8154af5611249866c4bc394c256e225e05db21a784 serviceName=whoami-traefik2-test
```

So traefik expects the globally valid name for the network and doesn't care about that it was started from inside the compose project. You can validate the network names by doing a

```
docker container inspect XXX_whoami_1
```

where XXX is the name of your docker-compose project.

What can you do now?

#### Solution 1: fix and reference the project name via env

Construct the network name accordingly, so that the param matches the globally unique name for the network that docker-compose creates. If all your target containers in this compose file are in the `web` network, you can even omit the special label on the target containers.

```yaml
    traefik:
      image: "traefik:v2.3"
      command:
        - --log.level=DEBUG
        - --api.insecure=true
        - --api.dashboard=true
        - --api.debug=true
        - --providers.docker=true
        - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
        - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
        - --providers.docker.network=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_web
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "8080:8080"
      volumes:
        - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      networks:
        - web
```

This requires you to pass a docker compose project name for each and every command (or have the env set accordingly)

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=proj docker-compose up
```

The issue with that is that you really need to specify that variable for each and every call. You might be able to fix that by using an `.env` file next to the `docker-compose.yml` that enables that.

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=projfromenv
```

#### Alternative solution: external network reference

But there might be a better solution. That second option is to use a globally unique network name by referencing an existing network. This needs initial setup of the network like so:

```
docker network create traefik-net
```

And then referencing it in the networks section:

```
networks:
  web:
    external: true
    name: traefik-net
  backend:
```

And starting traefik with the reference to this network name (snippet):

```
- --providers.docker.network=traefik-net
```

Your target containers still reference the local network name `web` which is now a reference to that global one. You should not need to specifiy the traefik network label for the whoami containers because you don't need to overwrite the default.

This setup also allows to spin up other compose projects with containers that also should get exposed from this traefik instance. So I'd go with that second option...

Comment: Neved did I expect such detailed explanation, hats off to you my good Sir!